# Allow spaces between each chracter

Tags: php, regex

I would like to allow numbers and the following characters: `-`, `+`, `(`, `)`

```
$phone = '1(54)+45-21';
var_dump(preg_match('/^[\(\)0-9+-]+$/', $phone));
```

Well, that works great. But I would also like to allow spaces between each character. So the value of `$phone` could be like `+45 (548) - 541 55 11` but it would also be valid without any spaces.

How can I allow optional spaces?

Comment: Perhaps this page is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: Just add a space to the character list?

Comment: I have tried it with `/^[()0-9+-? ]+$/`. That works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to predict all the nonsensical ways people can pick to write a phone number will do nothing but erode your sanity.

```
$phone = '+1 (234) 567-8900';

// 1. Delete all non-consequential characters.
$phone_bare = preg_replace('/[^\d+]/', '', $phone);

// 2. Check against a simple, sane format.
//      eg: optional +, 11 digits
$result = preg_match('/^\+?\d{11}$/', $phone_bare);

var_dump($phone, $phone_bare, $result);
```

Output:

```
string(17) "+1 (234) 567-8900"
string(12) "+12345678900"
int(1)
```